# How to curl rails page from same rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I need to curl a rails page from same rails application. I have something rendered on this url: http://localhost:3000/. Now I need to curl that url form http://localhost:3000/my_controller/my_method. I used Httparty to curl that page (HTTParty.get('http://localhost:3000/'). On doing this, the page shows loading only and does not do any processing. Rails log also shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are starting your application via `rails s` or `rails server`, so all requests handled by WEBRick server. It is single-threaded/single-process server, so it could not handle concurrent requests.

In order to make HTTP request to the same application from controller you need to use other server(like https://github.com/puma/puma).

But it isn't good practice to make HTTP request directly from controllers. Could you describe your goal?

Comment: Actually, I need to generate html contents to pdf. I used some gems like pdfkit, wicked_pdf for this. They are useful but they fail to render svg elements. So, I decided to run linux terminal commands from rails using  system command => system("wkhtmltopdf http://localhost:3000/ #{Rails.root}/public/html.pdf"). This command works on command line (ubuntu) but not in rails. I tried to curl http://localhost:3000/ page and write content into html.html file. But that too did not work.

Comment: So you need to use concurrent webserver to run your application. Because with default server requests are served one-by-one, so your `HTTParty.get('http://localhost:3000/'` request ain't going to be served till previous request (which is calling HTTPparty.get).